# error when copying images from a folder on a recurring basis

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans, and I want to copy images from one folder to another. Everything works fine when there are no subfolders. The problem is that if I have a subfolder it doesn't copy the images it contains. I need to copy all the images including the ones inside the subfolders.

```
    public static void recursivo(File ruta) {

    String user = System.getProperty("user.name");

    File[] listarFichero = ruta.listFiles();
    if (listarFichero != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < listarFichero.length; i++) {

            if (listarFichero[i].isDirectory()) {
                try {
                   
                    recursivo(listarFichero[i]);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            } else {

                if (listarFichero[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Thumbs.db") || listarFichero[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Desktop.ini")) {
                    listarFichero[i].isHidden();
                }

                try {
             
                    CopiarDeUnaCarpetaAotra.copia("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos\\" + listarFichero[i].getName(), "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos\\pipi\\" + listarFichero[i].getName());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method copies the images from one folder to another:

```
   public static void copia(String ficheroOriginal, String ficheroCopia) {
    try {
        
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ficheroOriginal);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ficheroCopia);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

       
        byte[] array = new byte[2048];
        int leidos = bis.read(array);

        while (leidos > 0)
        {
            bos.write(array, 0, leidos);
            leidos = bis.read(array);
        }

       
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     
    }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of empty catch blocks in your code. Any error could be occurring and you would never know. Remove the try/catches and let the exceptions be thrown so you can see what's wrong.

Comment: I have tried it without the try catch and the result is the same. It does not throw any errors. The problem is that it does not fit into the subfolders.